# Azure DevOps Rest API not keeping System.AreaPath and System.IterationPath

Tags: json, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the Azure DevOps (TFS) Rest API to create new work items. When I submit the request the json data that I send has the correct information for the AreaPath and Iteration path:

```
[
   {
      'op':'add',
      'path':'fields/System.Title',
      'from':null,
      'value':'Earthquake markers'
   },
   {
      'op':'add',
      'path':'fields/System.WorkItemType',
      'from':null,
      'value':'Task'
   },
   {
      'op':'add',
      'path':'fields/System.TeamProject',
      'from':null,
      'value':'UMC_Sitecore'
   },
   {
      'op':'add',
      'path':'fields/System.AreaPath',
      'from':null,
      'value':'UMC_Sitecore\Leaders'
   },
   {
      'op':'add',
      'path':'fields/System.IterationPath',
      'from':null,
      'value':'UMC_Sitecore\49 Early Sept'
   },
   {
      'op':'add',
      'path':'fields/System.Tags',
      'from':null,
      'value':'Pre-Grooming'
   },
   {
      'op':'add',
      'path':'fields/System.Description',
      'from':null,
      'value':' test'
   }
]
```

However the response json defaults to the TeamProject for the AreaPath and Iteration Path:

```
{
   {
      "System.WorkItemType":"Task",
      "System.AreaPath":"UMC_Sitecore",
      "System.TeamProject":"UMC_Sitecore",
      "System.IterationPath":"UMC_Sitecore",
      "System.State":"To Do",
      "System.Reason":"New task",
      "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate":"1753-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "System.ChangedBy":{
         "displayName":"Romero, Tim",
         "url":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/_apis/Identities/6d8a568d-3cf9-420b-9797-49b85b07b1f6",
         "_links":{
            "avatar":{
               "href":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/win.Uy0xLTUtMjEtNjY3ODkyNjQ1LTgzMTIwMTE1Ni0yMDI1MzUwMDg3LTU5MDgw"
            }
         },
         "id":"6d8a568d-3cf9-420b-9797-49b85b07b1f6",
         "uniqueName":"UMCOM_CENTRAL\\tromero",
         "imageUrl":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=6d8a568d-3cf9-420b-9797-49b85b07b1f6",
         "descriptor":"win.Uy0xLTUtMjEtNjY3ODkyNjQ1LTgzMTIwMTE1Ni0yMDI1MzUwMDg3LTU5MDgw"
      },
      "System.CreatedBy":{
         "displayName":"Romero, Tim",
         "url":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/_apis/Identities/6d8a568d-3cf9-420b-9797-49b85b07b1f6",
         "_links":{
            "avatar":{
               "href":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/win.Uy0xLTUtMjEtNjY3ODkyNjQ1LTgzMTIwMTE1Ni0yMDI1MzUwMDg3LTU5MDgw"
            }
         },
         "id":"6d8a568d-3cf9-420b-9797-49b85b07b1f6",
         "uniqueName":"UMCOM_CENTRAL\\tromero",
         "imageUrl":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=6d8a568d-3cf9-420b-9797-49b85b07b1f6",
         "descriptor":"win.Uy0xLTUtMjEtNjY3ODkyNjQ1LTgzMTIwMTE1Ni0yMDI1MzUwMDg3LTU5MDgw"
      },
      "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority":2
   },
   "_links":{
      "workItemType":{
         "href":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/5f12db4f-f69b-45ac-8d18-dcae5a3177ab/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Task"
      },
      "fields":{
         "href":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/5f12db4f-f69b-45ac-8d18-dcae5a3177ab/_apis/wit/fields"
      }
   },
   "url":"https://code.umcom.org/UMCom_DefaultCollection/5f12db4f-f69b-45ac-8d18-dcae5a3177ab/_apis/wit/workItems"
}
```

Is there something incorrect in in my json formatting or is there something about the API that needs to be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with LJ.

In addition, I recommend that you use `""` instead of `''`. Please refer this [doc](https://medium.com/@sandeepsinh/create-work-item-with-rest-api-in-azure-devops-28f979a12f37) for more details.

A skeleton version looks like this:

```
[
 {
 "op": "add",
 "path": "/fields/System.Title",
 "from": null,
 "value": "Sample Bug"
 },
 {
 "op": "add",
 "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
 "from": null,
 "value": "test0002\\test02"
 },
 {
 "op": "add",
 "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
 "from": null,
 "value": "test0002\\testa"
 }
]
```

And result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `AreaPath` and `IterationPath` values:

- from `'value':'UMC_Sitecore\Leaders'` to `'value':'UMC_Sitecore\\Leaders'`
- from `'value':'UMC_Sitecore\49 Early Sept'` to `'value':'UMC_Sitecore\\49 Early Sept'`

The backslash is a reserved character in JSON and you cannot just simply use it that way.